# How to have an x*y grid that splits viewport (entire width and height) without Flexbox support

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have a grid occupying the entire viewport where each cells have the exact same dimensions and are equally using the entire viewport width and height.

As I need to display a *x* * *y* table/grid where *x* and *y* can go up to 20, I would like to avoid using divided percentages (100/2=50%, 100/3=33.33%, 25%, 20%, 16.67%, 14.29%, 12.5%, etc.) width and height.

(Small) constraint: Using Opera 12.00 which does not support CSS3 Flexbox.

I don't really need rows/columns concept: it can be multiple `<div>` *floated* in line...

Here is, in Flexbox, what I am aiming to:

HTML:

```
<div id="matrix-container">
    <div class="matrix-row">
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x1</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x2</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x3</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x4</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="matrix-row">
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x1</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x2</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x3</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x4</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="matrix-row">
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x1</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x2</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x3</div></div>
        <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x4</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#matrix-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
.matrix-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

.matrix-cell {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.matrix-cell-content {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly38bsrr/

Can it be done without Flexbox? Or is there a Flexbox-support via JavaScript that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS tables:

```css
#matrix-container {
  display: table; /* Table layout */
  height: 100%;   /* Fill all the window vertically */
  width: 100%;    /* Fill all the window horizontally */
}
.matrix-row {
  display: table-row; /* Row */    
}
.matrix-cell {
  display: table-cell; /* Cell */
}
```

Now we will force all columns to have the same width. For that, we will use the [`fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) algorithm, which is well-defined and usually faster than the [`auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) one. According to that algorithm,

> 1. A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property [...]
> 2. Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property [...]
> 3. Any remaining columns **equally divide** the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing).

So just don't impose any width to the columns nor the cells, and we are done.

Now let's see the [heights](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout):

> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by
>   the content.

Therefore, if the cells have contents with different heights, the rows may have different heights too!

But since you have wrappers inside the cells, we can force them to have no height (and let the contents overflow). Thus all cells will have an initial height of 0.

```css
.matrix-cell-content {
  height: 0;
}
```

There is only a problem:

> CSS 2.1 **does not define** how extra space is distributed when the
>   'height' property causes the table to be taller than it otherwise
>   would be.

But most implementations distribute it equally. So no problem.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#matrix-container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.matrix-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.matrix-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.matrix-cell-content {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="matrix-container">
  <div class="matrix-row">
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x1</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x2</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x3</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">1x4</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-row">
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x1</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x2</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x3</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">2x4</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-row">
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x1</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x2</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x3</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">3x4</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-row">
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">4x1</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">4x2</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">4x3</div></div>
    <div class="matrix-cell"><div class="matrix-cell-content">4x4</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! If you had some extra directives to avoid too large text in `<div class="matrix-cell-content">` to get out of the cell (for edge cases where content is too long) that would be even more great...

Comment: @CDuv To let it overflow gracefully, I think the best would be removing `height:0` and using absolute positioning: `.matrix-cell {position: relative} .matrix-cell-content{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0}`. An then you can add `.matrix-cell-content{overflow:auto; word-wrap:break-word}`.